# How to get Database name of sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get Database name of a specific Database in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To get the current database name use `select db_name()`.

[DB_NAME(Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

or

```
select name from sys.sysdatabases 
where dbid=db_id()
```

or

```
select DB_NAME(db_id())
```