# How can I SELECT the name of the Active Database?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select the name of the Db on which I am running a query and PRINT it.

How can I achieve this in T-SQL?

something like:

```
DECLARE @ActualDbName VARCHAR(200)
SET @ActualDbName  = -- SELECT ...
PRINT @ActualDbName
```

Comment: This may be what you are looking for. 
[Get Database Name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774533/how-to-get-database-name-of-sqlserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function DB_NAME().

So you would replace your -- SELECT -- with something like:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];
```

Specified here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName

Courtesy : [Source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/12/sql-server-get-current-database-name/)